# value in array of maps is overwritten in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, maps, overwrite

I have written a recursive function that will generate map  and put into an array.
one of the field in the previous maps is getting overwritten when a new map is getting pushed

```js
var out = new Array();

function fun(results, count, path, current) {

  var p = [];
  p = path;
  p.push(current)
  if (typeof(results.NEXT) == 'undefined') {
    var result = new Map();

    result = {
      "TotalCount": count,
      "Path": p,
      "title": results.name
    }


    out.push(result)
    console.log(out) //each time the old map getting overwritten
  } else {

    for (var i = 0; i < (results.NEXT.length); i++) {
      var curCount = results.NEXT[i].count
      fun(results.NEXT[i], count + curCount, path, curCount)
      path.pop();
    }

  }

}
var path = [];


var results = {
  name: 'Prdct Dev - Prof 4',
  NEXT: [{
      name: 'Sales Research - Mgmt 4',
      count: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'Distr- Brokers & Agt - Prof 5',
      count: 6
    }
  
   
  ],
  count: 6
}

fun(results, 6, path, 6)
console.log("function excution complete")

console.log(out)
```

The first map path value got overwritten with second one.
Why is this happening?
How to solve this?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There are a number of problems here, but without knowing what your `results` object looks like there's not much help to offer. (Though you aren't creating a Map, you're declaring a Map and then immediately overwriting it with an object.)

Comment: Yes, please give us code that we can run. What does `results.data.queryTitle[0].NEXT[0]` look like? `Minimum reproducible example`

Comment: The basic problem is you are using the same array reference for each object. So if you push or pop it affects all since they are all the same array. Try making a copy of the array before mutating it

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: @pilchard I have provided the code snippet,  here I am seeing /**ref:3**/ and   /**id:3**/,  in the output which I havent seen in my console. What do they mean?

Comment: @TKoL I have provided the example, After running the snippet i see   /**ref:3**/ and /**id:3**/ which  i havent seen in my console. If we see the result in the second iteration the first map path is also getting changed, how can I prevent that?

Comment: completely separate issue, but I also don't really understand where this `/**ref:3**/ and /**id:3**/` stuff comes from. Pretty strange. Must be a bug related to their little code sandbox.

Comment: Those `/**id:N**/` and `/**ref:N**/` allow the console to show cyclic structures and other structures where nodes are reused, without overflowing the console.  `/**id:N**/` notes that the structure to immediately follow will have later references back to it.  `/**ref:N**/` says that a reference to that node should be included here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var p = [];
  p = path;
```

What's the point of these two lines of code? Do you want to use the same `path` every iteration, or do you want every iteration of the function to have its own path?

The way it's coded, it's the same as just writing `var p = path;`, and every iteration you're pushing to it and then popping.

If you want to make a copy of the array for every element of `out`, then do that with `slice` in this code:

```
    result = {
      "TotalCount": count,
      "Path": p.slice(),
      "title": results.name
    }
```